# What determines whether InstanceDir has a full or relative path?

Tags: solr, solr4

With Solr 4.x, http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores returns an XML description of loaded cores, which indicates the file path location of the `instanceDir`.

```
...
<lst name="collection1">
 <str name="name">collection1</str>
 <bool name="isDefaultCore">true</bool>
 <str name="instanceDir">C:\solr\solr-4.10.1\example\solr\collection1\</str>
...
```

On my Windows 7 PC, this is presented as a full path, but others have reported this as relative path.  What factors can cause this value to be presented as a relative path, and is there a way to force this to be presented as a full path?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please confirm if you have set solr.home. Please check this [Solr Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%20(supported%20through%204.x)) for more details. I hope setting solr.home should resolve the issue.

You can add it as JVM argument

```
java -Dsolr.solr.home=/your/solr/home/path/here -jar start.jar
```

Incase of Tomcat, you can also do as below

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsolr.solr.home=/your/solr/home/path/here"
```

Thanks

Comment: How would this be set? From the command line when launching Solr?

Comment: I try to run the following command but it fails. Am I missing something?  

    `C:\Solr-4.7.2\example> java -Dsolr.solr.home=C:\Solr-4.7.2\example -jar start.jar`

    `Error: Could not find or load main class .solr.home=C:\Solr-4.7.2\example`

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty because the information and documentation link are helpful, but I'm leaving the question marked as unanswered because I'm still looking for the factors that lead the path to be expressed as relative in the /solr/admin/cores response. I need this information to update documentation.

Comment: @SergeyShushlyapin,I was able to get this to work. I copied my collection1 directory to D:\solr\temp, and then this command launched Solr successfully to port 9999: `D:\solr\solr-4.7.2\example>java -Dsolr.solr.home=D:\solr\temp -jar start.jar -Dj
etty.port=9999`  As I noted above, I still don't understand why you weren't seeing the full path.

Comment: @DanSolovay, yes, it works but only if executed from `cmd`. In PowerShell it fails with the error above, but that is another issue (I guess).